# Python: Print key and values in sorted order of values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am learning python coding and wanted to get some help with sorting dictionary. Based on information available on the internet, I was able to figure out how to sort a dictionary by keys and by values. However, I am having trouble trying to find a way to sort and print the key, value pair if i sort by values.
Here's my code:

```
fish = {'Chicago':300, 'San Francisco':200, 'Dallas':450, 'Seattle': 325, 'New York City': 800, 'Los Angeles':700, 'San Diego':650}
for i in sorted(fish): print (i, fish[i])

#The above loop will print the items from the dictionary in sorted order of keys.

for i in sorted(fish.items()): print (i)
#The above loop will print the items in sorted order of keys. It will print as a tuple.

for i in sorted(fish.values()): print (i)
#The above loop will print the items in sorted order by values.

#end of code
```

Is there a way to print the list of key value pairs from a dictionary in sorted order of values.

My result should be

- San Francisco 200
- Chicago 300
- Seattle 325
- Dallas 450
- San Diego 650
- Los Angeles 700
- New York City 800

One of the way to do this is:

```
def by_value(item): return item[1]
for k, v in sorted(fish.items(), key=by_value): print (k,v)
```

I don't want to define a function. I want a for loop with sorted command. Is there any? I am not sure if a lambda function will do this. I haven't tried it. That's my next step.

stackoverflow provided me a response. Looks like this was asked and answered. So cool.

[How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Hint: look at the `key` parameter that you can pass to `sorted` which governs how things are sorted

Comment: `for i in sorted(fish, key=fish.get): print (i, fish[i])`.

Comment: Thank You for the hint @donkopotamus. The key parameter in the sorted function did wonders for me.  https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#:~:text=Key%20Functions

Comment: Thank You for the hint @Henry Yik. Your response gave me the "key" to my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sort using value by lambda:**

```
sorted(fish.items(), key=lambda k: k[1])
```

> To print key and values in sorted order of values.

```
for k, v in sorted(fish.items(), key=lambda k: k[1]):
    print(k)
    print(v)
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your response. Much appreciated.